# Может ли слово "нет" входить в грамматическую основу и быть сказуемым?

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор, основа

> Мы полагаем, что во всякой истине всегда есть нечто ложное и что сходство между истиной и ложью так велико, что нет такого отличительного признака, на основании которого можно было бы судить наверняка.

Подчеркнула в части предложения *"что нет такого отличительного признака"* слово *"нет"* как сказуемое. Верно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы: в данном случае "нет" - это сказуемого. "Нет" может употребляться как сказуемое в значении: ***не имеется в наличии; отсутствует (противоп.: есть).***

> **См.: Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
>   Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
>   Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.**

Answer (score 2):

Это сказуемое в безличном предложении. Структурная схема: нет - N2.

[Открыть](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1908-1914.html) нужную страницу РГ-80.

Answer (score 1):

Тут вот какая штука. 
Главный член односоставного предложения по современной моде перестали называть сказуемым (и подлежащим, естественно). Просто - "главный член". И в этом смысле надо оговориться, что "нет" не есть сказуемое, но именно главный член. Суть от того не меняется.
Если вопрос в этом, то он больше терминологический, поинтересуйтесь у преподавателя, как он предпочитает называть этот главный член.

В остальном - все правильно.